# multithreading in php 5.6 in Xampp

Tags: php, multithreading

i tried all 
i.e : 
 - Move php_pthreads.dll to the 'bin\php\ext\' directory.
 - Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\php\' directory.
 - Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'bin\apache\bin' directory.
 - Move pthreadVC2.dll to the 'C:\windows\system32' directory.
 - 'extension=php_pthreads.dll' placed the line in php.ini

and after all i also restarted xampp but 
still error Class 'Thread' not found

Answer (score 2):

pthreads to NOT work with webservers like Apache. They only work with CLI.

See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php:

**Warning: The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server environment. Threading in PHP is therefore restricted to CLI-based applications only.**

Comment: I'm using it in local server in xampp

Comment: @SahilDhiman it won't work, see the first warning on http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Comment: Did you add `extension=php_pthreads.dll` to the correct php.ini for your CLI install?

Comment: i added it in the xampp/php/php.ini file